# I am new to scss. I have a laravel project in which frontend is already build (pre-develope theme) . Now i am facing problem with working in scss

Tags: css, laravel, sass, gulp

I am new to scss. I have a laravel project in which frontend is already build (pre-develope theme) . Now i am facing problem with working in scss. My folder structure look like this.[image] I have installed gulp.js (installed fine) now when i create a new scss file it also regenerate the same file as .css in that folder how to encounter this problem.

Here is also my gulp.js file

```
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var sass        = require('gulp-sass');

// Compile sass into CSS & auto-inject into browsers
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src("scss/*.scss")
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("/css"))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

// Static Server + watching scss/html files
gulp.task('serve', gulp.series('sass', function() {

    browserSync.init({
        server: "./app/"
    });

    gulp.watch("scss/*.scss", gulp.series('sass'));
    gulp.watch("*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
}));

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('serve'));
```

Comment: After reading your question, it's not exactly clear what the problem or expected outcome is. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: i want to use sass with laravel

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you've installed all node modules and gulp globally.

From your cli:
change dir to frontend (where your gulp.js lies ). Or if you are using vscode, right click on frontend folder and press "open in integrated terminal".

```
cd frontend
```

run gulp task serve:

```
gulp serve
```